# Fill out text field within an element

Tags: javascript, element, document, nessus

I know there are already some threads about accessing an element within another element...I tried a lot of stuff but I can't get it to work...

JSFiddle -> http://jsfiddle.net/YcPc8/2/

What I want to do on the page is to fill out the username and the password - then click the login button.

Here is a part of the html code of the webpage:

```
    <section id="notifications"></section>
<div style="display: block;" id="login" class="">
    <div id="login-content">
        <form>
            <h1>Nessus Vulnerability Scanner</h1>

                <input name="login" tabindex="1" placeholder="Username" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off" spellcheck="false" class="required login-username" type="text">
                <i class="glyphicons username"></i>

                <input name="password" tabindex="2" placeholder="Password" maxlength="128" autocomplete="off" class="required login-password" type="password">
                <i class="glyphicons password"></i>

                <div id="remember-me" class="floatleft">
                    <div class="checkbox login-remember"></div>
                    <span class="floatleft">Remember Me</span>
                </div>

                <button type="submit" id="sign-in" tabindex="3" class="button secondary login floatright">Sign In</button>

        </form>
        <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="clear"></div>
<h2>Tenable Network Security</h2>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

Now I want to fill in the login and the password field...
Here is some of the code I tried within a javascript:

```
var nessus = window.open("https://localhost:8834/html5.html#/scans");
var doc = nessus.document.getElementById("login-content").getElementsByName("login");
doc.setAttribute("value","USERNAME");
```

Comment: Please create a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) with the relevant parts of your code.

Comment: What are you trying to do and what doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

element.getElementsByName("login") returns a list of elements. You might want to write this if you're sure it will return 1 element:

```
var doc = nessus.document.getElementsByName("login")[0];
```

EDIT : Moreover, getElementsByName is a method of the [*Document Interface*](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Core/core.html). You can't use it on node element.

You'd better give an ID to your username input field, and access it directly by

```
var doc = document.getElementById("usernameInput");
doc.value = "USERNAME";
```

JSFiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/YcPc8/4/